# Supporting legacy url with Next.js

Tags: next.js

I am writing a new Next.js app where legacy URLs have to be supported (I cant 301 redirect)

I need to support URLs like [www.dan.com/foo/bar/slug](http://www.dan.com/foo/bar/slug)

I currently have this folder structure.

> pages folder -> bar folder -> [slug].js

I would I route to this path?

Do I need to create a foo folder like this, and let the next conversion do the work, or are they other ways?

> pages folder -> foo folder -> bar folder -> [slug].js

Comment: Do you mean you are required to follow that URL structure and the page itself will live in your Next.js app, not externally?

Comment: Yes - the setup is kind of hard to explain, its essentially a Nextjs page that appears to be a part of another app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in your `next.config.js` to point the legacy URL structure to your Next.js page path.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/foo/bar/:slug',
                destination: '/bar/:slug'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably an obvious point - but this only works with serverside routes.